# NGINX target specific upload files on different folders

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location, noindex

I need to add a `noindex` tag to multiple specific uploaded files, but they all belong to different year and month upload folders like this for example:

- `/var/www/public/app/uploads/2021/06/file-1.pdf`
- `/var/www/public/app/uploads/2018/11/file-2.pdf`
- `/var/www/public/app/uploads/2011/07/file-3.pdf`

I did this initially, but did not work:

```
location ~ "^(.*)/app/uploads/(.*)$" {
    location ~ ^/(file-1.pdf|file-2.pdf|file-3.pdf)$ {
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
    }
}
```

I don't have access yet to test, but this is what I'm planning to do instead:

```
location ~ "/var/www/public/app/uploads/(.*)$" {
    location ~ ^/(file-1.pdf|file-2.pdf|file-3.pdf)$ {
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a better approach, or if this will even work. Right now there are 27 specific files I have to do this to so I'm not sure if the `file-1.pdf|file-2.pdf|file-3.pdf` is my best option.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are definitely use the `location` directive incorrectly. Assuming your server root directory is `/var/www/public/app` and your sample request is `http://example.com/uploads/2021/06/file-1.pdf` the *normalized* URI (which is subject to check for `location` or `rewrite` directives) will be `/uploads/2021/06/file-1.pdf`. An example of location that will catch those requests and add a required header is

```
location ~ ^/uploads/(?<file>.*) {
    if ($file ~ ^(?:2021/06/file-1\.pdf|2018/11/file-2\.pdf|2011/07/file-3\.pdf))$ {
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
    }
}
```

Here `(?<file>.*)` is so-called [named capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) for later usage. Using two nested locations is possible too:

```
location /uploads/ {
    location ~ /(?:2021/06/file-1\.pdf|2018/11/file-2\.pdf|2011/07/file-3\.pdf)$ {
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
    }
}
```

You can also use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive (although I don't know if this could be called "a better approach"):

```
map $file $robots {
    2021/06/file-1.pdf    noindex;
    2018/11/file-2.pdf    noindex;
    2011/07/file-3.pdf    noindex;
    # default value will be an empty string
}

server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/uploads/(?<file>.*) {
        add_header X-Robots-Tag $robots;
    }
    ...
}
```

or without regexes:

```
map $uri $robots {
    /uploads/2021/06/file-1.pdf    noindex;
    /uploads/2018/11/file-2.pdf    noindex;
    /uploads/2011/07/file-3.pdf    noindex;
    # default value will be an empty string
}

server {
    ...
    location /uploads/ {
        add_header X-Robots-Tag $robots;
    }
    ...
}
```

The `add_header` directive won't add a header to response if its second parameter will be an empty string.

You should also take in attention [this](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) documentation excerpt:

> These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.

Comment: Ah thank you! I thought I needed to use the whole directory for it — the first solution worked well for me except it's missing a closing parenthesis for the `if` condition.

I would have preferred to use the `map` since it's more manageable but it thows out a `nginx: [emerg] unknown "file" variable` for me.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is a regular copy-paste error, of course we should check an [`$uri`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) variable in the second `map` example. I agreed it looks more manageable than the other examples.